# Unable to Edit Sublime Text's Default Settings

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3

I would like to edit my default settings in Sublime Text 3 (beta build 3059) to not ignore the Vintage package - via *Preferences > Settings - Default*.  I am running Sublime Text on Windows 7 Pro x64.

The [Vintage package's documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html) says to edit and save the default settings file to enable Vintage mode:

[image: Sublime Text 3 Vintage Package Documentation]

When I click the *Settings - Default* menu item, the default `Preferences.sublime-settings` file opens with expected content; but I cannot edit it.  For example, deleting or backspacing to remove `"Vintage"` in `"ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]` does nothing.

I thought maybe the default settings file was marked readonly and tried to check it: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default\Preferences.sublime-settings` does not exist.  `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default` does not exist either.

To work around this, I tried to save the default settings file that Sublime Text opened for me - to see if that would create the `Default` directory and `Preferences.sublime-settings` in it.  Instead Sublime Text gave the following error:

> Unable to save C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default\Preferences.sublime-settings
>   Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Has anyone encountered this issue with Sublime Text 3 (specifically in trying to enable Vintage mode or otherwise) and worked around it...or found an authoritative explanation for it?

I reason that next I could try to add the missing `Default` directory myself, create an empty `Preferences.sublime-settings` text file in it, and try again to save the default settings file that Sublime Text opened for me; but this is starting to feel kludgy.

Comment: I know a solution has been posted, but did you ever figure out why the file doesn't exist? I have the same problem; I'm on a Mac, but the "Default" folder was not created at all when running Sublime. Although the "User" file exists. And worse than you, my "Default" files are all empty rather than containing anything.

Comment: @Gary, they just simply changed the way you meant to apply the settings in the 3rd edition and haven't caught up with the documentation yet. It's Beta you know. Check my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should not edit the default settings.  Add the files you want to ignore to the file `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`.  You can open this file by going to `Preferences - >Settings - User`.  Anything you set here will override the default settings.

Comment: Thanks.  It may not change the bottom line, but note that I do not want to ignore the Vintage package, rather _not_ ignore it.

Comment: I read your [similar advice not to edit the default settings file on the ST3 forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11224).  The Vintage package's documentation is not consistent with this advice, though; and I agree with [mindlube](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=10821) (in the same ST3-forums thread) that ST3's handling of an attempt to edit the default settings is not very graceful or clear.  Maybe the _Preferences > Settings - Default_ menu item should rather be _Settings - Default (Readonly)_.

Comment: @J0e3gan Depending on if you are overriding the packaged files, it may or may not be read only. If you feel you really need to modify the defaults, use https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer to open the file. Then make your edit and save. It will place the file in the proper location to override the existing file. Also note that if you were to go through the menu again and make an edit. It would save as you expect. Guess I forgot to follow up on that post. Honestly, I don't really reference the official docs all that much. They seem to be rarely updated and incomplete.

Comment: My guess is that page is a duplicate of the docs he had for ST2, even though handling of packages has changed. Oh if you are working with ST3, you may be interested in using https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous instead of the built in vintage. It appears to be much more feature complete, and under active  (visible) development. I'd assume all "Default" settings for any plugin are read only. But you can create a file of the same name in the User package, and it will merge with the defaults, overriding where appropriate.

Comment: @GerardONeill That has to due with how ST3 packages files. You can in fact "edit" the defaults, though it takes a few extra steps compared to ST2. I mentioned should not edit because the original question specified making an empty file. This is how you would edit (override) the packaged files in ST3.

Comment: I suppose I was a little terse -- I meant via the UI.  It seems to me the intended functionality was that the defaults remain unedited, but rather to create your own using the 'Settings -- user' menu item.  Obviously there would be 'work arounds'..  But I came here for the exact reason that J0e3gan did..  But your post did create the aha moment, and thank you for that.  Just thought it could be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want to **Not** ignore the *Vintage* rather.
This still can be done using the `Preferences.sublime-setting-User`. AFAIK, any value given in this file overwrites the entries in `Preferences.sublime-setting-Default`.

Simply add this line with the `"Vintage"` removed in it to your *User* preferences and you'll be fine. (Remember to save the file after you did the edit and the change will happen instantly)

Also, not that VI mode in sublime is on *edit* more by default so make sure you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first to make sure VI is activated.

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
    "ignored_packages": []
}
```

---

**Update**

The latest format is,

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
      // Line below is commented out to enable Vintage.
      //"Vintage"
    ],

    // To start Sublime in Command moder 
    // rather than Insert mode.
    "vintage_start_in_command_mode": true
}
```

Comment: According to [these docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html): 

You can also change that insert mode setting with `"vintage_start_in_command_mode": true`

Comment: What you mentioned is a true fact however it only works (by enabling to enter into sublime with Command mode rather than Insert Mode when it started) if the vi is enabled already.

Answer (score 1):

Install 'PackageResourceViewer' from 'Install Package' in the Command Palette.

Then use 'PackageResourceViewer' command in the Command Palette.

Use that to extract/open the default packages you previously were unable to.

More information here : https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer

Answer (score 0):

I use Sublime Text3 recently in Windows 10. I'm trying to change the file: Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings. And met your problem "Enable to sa ve Preferences.sublime-settings".
I solve this by changing file Preferences.sublime-settings's property, in Security, edit "user"'s permissions. Allowed to modify.
And then I can edit and save Preferences.sublime-settings

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX (Ventura) I had to combine both @skuroda and @Mehrad's answers to achieve enabling Vintage mode.

1. Navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages/User
2. Create a file named `Preferences.sublime-setting` (vim Preferences.sublime-setting)
3. Paste the following

   // Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
   // and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
   {
   "ignored_packages": []
   }
4. Save and exit (`:x` or `:wq`)
5. Result is instant, you should now be able to enter and exit insert mode in Sublime Text

Answer (score -1):

When I install Sublime Text in Linux, I report the message `NOTADIRECTORYERROR: [ERRNO 20] NOT A DIRECTORY`. At first I thought it was because the Defalut folder was missing, but later I realized it wasn't. I then checked the Settings of my SublimeREPL. Sublime-setings and deleted the contents after bin, and found that the program worked fine.

old: `"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/home/bgnv5/anaconda3/bin/python"}`,

new: `"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/home/bgnv5/anaconda3/bin/"}`,

Spent a lot of time to find problems, I hope to help you.